# OpenLayers 4 Overview map click event

Tags: javascript, openlayers

How can I enable the click event to move the overview map in OpenLayers 4?

Here the code from the example, the same as I use

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
    new ol.control.OverviewMap()
  ]),
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [500000, 6000000],
    zoom: 7
  })
});
```

Sorry if I don't put my code but I use the same code, and neither on the example, you are able to click on a part of the overview map and move the box and the main map, It seems that you can do it just with a drag option.

What I want to achieve is the possibility to click on a part of the overview map and move the box to the mouse location and in this way center also the master map without needs to go to the box in the overview map with the mouse and drag it to move booth views

Comment: Do you want to reposition where the overview displays itself?

Comment: I want to center the overview and the master map where I click on the overview map, without need to use the drag option. (go to the box in the overview map with the mouse and drag it to move the map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you're referring to is apparently: [Overview Map Control](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overviewmap.html)

Looking at the source code for [overviewmap.js](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/v4.6.4/src/ol/control/overviewmap.js) you can see it creates the following:

```js
var box = document.createElement('DIV');
box.className = 'ol-overviewmap-box';
```

So you if you use JQuery you could center the overview horizontally with something like:

```
$(".ol-overviewmap-box").css('left', '50%');
```

or [manipulate it's position](https://api.jquery.com/position/) when clicking the overview.

Comment: Is the only example I found, no other examples talk about overview map, You can move the overview map with the drag option but not with a click, I have to found a parameter to insert into `new ol.control.OverviewMap()` ?

Comment: maybe I can use something like `overviewmap.on("click, function(){}")` but what exactly I've to target to move the map and the minimap? The overview map what I use to select it and get the view to get the coordinates?
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.control.OverviewMap.html#on

Comment: @Sebastiano updated my answer based on your comments

Comment: So I need to select `.ol-overviewmap-map.on(click)` it seems the main div for the overview map and with `position()` move the parent of `.ol-overviewmap-box` ? If you inspect the div you will see that the one with the `position absolute` is the parent and not the box itself

Comment: `$(".ol-overviewmap-map").on("click", function(e) {
  var div = $(".ol-overviewmap-map").offset();
  var x = e.pageX - div.left;     // Get the horizontal coordinate
  var y = e.pageY - div.top;    // Get the vertical coordinate
  var coor = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
  console.log(coor);

  $(".ol-overlay-container").css("left", x);
  $(".ol-overlay-container").css("top", y);

});` In this way, I can manipulate the parent but the master map doesn't change center, I can work on it